# how to add multiple Druid filters

Tags: druid

For example I have the following Druid query:

```
"filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "city",
        "value": "landon"
      },
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "name",
        "value": "Tom"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I'd like to add a NOT field, where should I insert it?
The mapping SQL like:
select * from User where city='landon' and name="Tom" and title<>"teacher".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer as following:

```
"filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "city",
        "value": "landon"
      },
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "name",
        "value": "Tom"
      },
      {
        "field": {
          "type": "selector",
          "dimension": "title",
          "value": "teacher"
        },
        "type": "not"
      }
    ]
  }
```